raylib When resizing the window, the background is black
I am using raylib, when I create a basic project, I want to make the window resizable, when I resize the window, the background is black, why is this, how can I make the window background not black.
Sorry, I didn't find the answer on google.
Here is my code:
// RaylibCMakeProject.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//
#include "raylib.h"

#include "RaylibCMakeProject.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello CMake." << endl;
    // Initialization
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    static int screenWidth = 800;
    static int screenHeight = 450;

    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "raylib [core] example - basic window");
    //SetWindowState(FLAG_VSYNC_HINT);
    SetWindowState(FLAG_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
    //SetWindowState(FLAG_MSAA_4X_HINT);

    SetTargetFPS(60);               // Set our game to run at 60 frames-per-second
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Main game loop
    while (!WindowShouldClose())    // Detect window close button or ESC key
    {
        // Update
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // TODO: Update your variables here
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Draw
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        BeginDrawing();

        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);

        DrawText("Congrats! You created your first window!", 190, 200, 20, LIGHTGRAY);

        EndDrawing();
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }

    // De-Initialization
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CloseWindow();        // Close window and OpenGL context
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    return 0;
}



https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/issues/1680 seems the maintainer chose not to add this functionality as it is not worth it ..... i know SDL supports this, which raylib could use as a backend, so in theory you could use SDL backend then attach a resize handler and use that to fix your issue (easier said than done) ... or just switch to SDL directly .... or just not bother with this problem.

Yes, this is annoying. However, it is a rather rare edge case that fixes itself instantly. Do you really want to spike the CPU by rerendering every time the mouse moves a pixel?

@Botje How to fix it? for a simple program, I think it will take up some CPU. That's no problem.

You fix it by sending a patch to the raylib developer. This is way beyond the scope of a SO question.
